# Android onTouch() makes sound like double tap

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, touch-event, ontouch

I've implemented `onTouch` for my layout to function as buttons.
It all works great besides the fact that a 2 clicks sound is made sometimes as touching the button.
I've tried to debug it but I wasn't able to understand what is the problem.

Here is the `onTouch` code :

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch "+event.getAction());
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.main_menu_buttons_bg_pressed);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_color);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.main_menu_buttons_bg_pressed);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d(TAG, "on click");
                v.performClick();
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_color);
                break;
            default:
                // empty    
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

As you can see I've added log messages, which usually prints :

```
onTouch 0
onTouch 2
onTouch 2
onTouch 2
onTouch 2
onTouch 1
on click
```

so it should be ok but yet the clicks are heard twice (sometimes, can't determine exactly when it happens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the expected behaviour du of `v.performClick();` , when the view has also an `OnClikListener`: From GrepCode

```
2480    public boolean More ...performClick() {
2481        sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
2482
2483        if (mOnClickListener != null) {
2484            playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
2485            mOnClickListener.onClick(this);
2486            return true;
2487        }
2488
2489        return false;
2490    }
```

Comment: So how can I avoid it?

Comment: on the button's instance try `button.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);`

Comment: Thank you both. I've disabled sound effects.. I couldn't figure how to avoid it

Comment: Can also be done from XML:  `android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"`